# Adding a 2px border exclusively between images in a grid

Tags: html, css

**I'm using [this](https://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/responsive-full-width-grid/) responsive grid to display images and my goal is to add a 2px border exclusively *between* images (where they 'touch'), without it appearing on the outside of the grid.**

[Here's a link to a codepen example](https://codepen.io/androbaut/pen/NjrzvX)

```css
/*
----------*Grid*----------
*/


.cbp-rfgrid {
 margin: 0 0 0 0;
 padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;

}

.cbp-rfgrid li {
 position: relative;
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
 width: 33.3333333%; /* Fallback */
 width: -webkit-calc(100% / 3);
 width: calc(100% / 3);
}


.cbp-rfgrid li a,
.cbp-rfgrid li a img {
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 cursor: pointer;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a img {
 max-width: 100%;
}

/* Flexbox is used for centering the heading */
.cbp-rfgrid li a div {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 background: rgba(255,255,255,1);
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-align-items: center;
 -moz-align-items: center;
 -ms-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a:hover div {
 opacity: 1;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a div h3 {
 width: 100%;
 color: #000;
 padding: 0 10px;
}
@media (max-width: 767px){
  .cbp-rfgrid li a div h3 {
    font-size: 2.375em;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 768px){
  .cbp-rfgrid li a div h3 {
    font-size: 3.375em;
  }
}

/* Example for media query: change number of items per row */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
 .cbp-rfgrid li {
  width: 100%;
 }
}
```

```html
<ul class="cbp-rfgrid">
   <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" /><div><h3>Bukau</h3></div></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" /><div><h3>Noriko Olling</h3></div></a></li>
     <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" /><div><h3>Erba</h3></div></a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" /><div><h3>Raiso Japan</h3></div></a></li>
       <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" /><div><h3>Aaltoin</h3></div></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" /><div><h3>Bukau</h3></div></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" /><div><h3>Noriko Olling</h3></div></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" /><div><h3>Erba</h3></div></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" /><div><h3>Raiso Japan</h3></div></a></li>
<!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

I've tried playing around with margins & changing the grid behavior to accomplish this, but haven't found an appropriate solution so far.

Any advice and/or suggestions are greatly appreciated!

(*Codepen adds an 8px margin despite the grid being fullwidth, so preventing that from becoming a 10px margin is my goal* :) )

P.S. I'm not married to this particular grid or anything, so if there's a better/different/more flexible method, I'm totally open to it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using pure flexbox-

Here is a snippet, with simplified code based on yours.

```css
/*
----------*Grid*----------
*/

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.cbp-rfgrid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.cbp-rfgrid li {
  flex: 0 30%;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
  list-style: none
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a div {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center
}

.cbp-rfgrid li a:hover div {
  opacity: 1;
  background: white
}
@media (max-width:767px) {
.cbp-rfgrid li {
 flex: 0 100%
}
}
```

```html
<ul class="cbp-rfgrid">
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" />
      <div>
        <h3>Bukau</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" />
      <div>
        <h3>Noriko Olling</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" />
      <div>
        <h3>Erba</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" />
      <div>
        <h3>Raiso Japan</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" />
      <div>
        <h3>Aaltoin</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" />
      <div>
        <h3>Bukau</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" />
      <div>
        <h3>Noriko Olling</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" />
      <div>
        <h3>Erba</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/y6zIhgP.jpg" />
      <div>
        <h3>Raiso Japan</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
  </li>
  <!-- ... -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion & example! I just need to make the grid take up the full window width & then all is well

Comment: just do the math. 30% (or what value you want) with margins and you will make it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your side note is the key piece of information in your question:

> *(Codepen adds an 8px margin despite the grid being fullwidth, so preventing that from becoming a 10px margin is my goal :) )*

That's not Codepen adding the margin. It's the browser.

Most (if not all) browsers give the `body` element an 8px margin. Its in their [***default style sheet***](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/sample.html).

You can override this rule yourself. Simply add this to your code:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

Also, the default setting for the [CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing?v=control) is `content-box`. This means that width and height calculations you apply will only include the *content box*. Padding and borders will be added separately.

You can override this setting with `box-sizing: border-box`, which tells the browser that your width and height settings must include the *content box*, *padding box* and *border box*. In other words, everything out to the border.

(Margins are always added separately.)

Here's an illustration of the CSS Box Model:

[image]

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wdWxME)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My question at this point: if we take the border of '.cbp-rfgrid li' down to 1px, it remains present on the outer edge of the image grid (as one might expect). My goal is to have a border appear only between images. Any idea how I might go about something like that?

Comment: Well, it really depends on your overall grid objective. But let's assume it's a fixed 3x3 grid. The you just need to know that the `border` property is a shorthand for `border-width`, `border-style` and `border-color`. So use `border-width` to remove borders from outer edges of each cell. Here's a rough example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZKOjyG